# statistical difference between four groups with age data

Tags: r, distributions, variance

I have four groups and in each group I have 12 cases.

```
G1  G2  G3  G4
914 723 948 990
942 698 843 990
954 739 849 1020
932 775 918 990
930 788 961 1050
904 717 852 1050
878 751 864 1080
957 794 840 1110
878 770 852 1110
868 751 854 1110
889 734 920 1110
888 753 884 1140
```

the observations represent age in days. 
How can I do statistic controlling of distribution of age between these 4 groups?

For example, how can I say whether G4 is older than the others?

Which post hoc test is needed for this type of data?
Solutions could be brought via excel, SPSS or R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate mean and standard deviation for each group (easily done in each of your suggested software) and then use a Student's T-test to check if they vary significantly. This, too, can be done in Excel, SPSS and R.